# How many points can a circle in space have in common with a Cassini oval in 3D?

Tags: geometry

Given :

A circle of radius $R$ with its center at the $XYZ$-origin (in space).

Two different fixed points in space $(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1})$ and $(x_{2},y_{2},z_{2})$ that can lie anywhere.
The product of the distances to these points equals a given constant $C$.
The latter two conditions define a Cassini oval.

How many points can this circle in space have in common with a Cassini oval in 3D?

This geometric puzzle creeps up in a project where I want to find out when/where signal strength will be maximum in a bistatic setup with a fixed transmitter and receiver, and a moving aircraft.

Comment: If it matters, the set of points $p$ satisfying $\|p - p_{1}\| \cdot \|p - p_{2}\| = C$ is not a hyperboloid.

Comment: You're absolutely right - it's a Cassini's oval. When their distance difference is a constant, it's an hyperboloid. I changed my question accordingly. Thanks for pointing this mistake out.

Comment: Are they not ovaloid surfaces obtained by rotating Cassinian ovals wrt the axis joining the foci?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection of the Cassini oval with the plane holding the circle is a quartic curve. By [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_theorem), when the number of intersection of that quartic curve with the circle is finite, then it is at most $8 = 4\times 2$.

Please note that it is possible for the quartic curve to intersect the circle at infinite many places. This can happen if the circle and Cassini oval share a common symmetry axis.

**Update**

It turns out for Cassini oval, when the number of intersection is finite, the maximum number of intersection is $4$ instead of $8$.

WOLOG, choose a coordinate system such that the circle lies on the $z = 0$ plane
with equation $$\mathcal{C} : x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$

If one "square" the defining relation of the Cassini oval and intersect it with
the $z = 0$ plane, its equation will have the form

$$\mathcal{O} : (x^2+y^2 + L_1(x,y))(x^2+y^2+L_2(x,y)) = C^2$$

where $L_i(x,y) = a_i x + b_i y + c$ are affine in $x,y$.

Notice for any $(x,y) \in\mathcal{C}$,

$$(x,y) \in \mathcal{O}\quad\iff\quad (r^2 + L_1(x,y))(r^2+L_2(x,y)) = C^2$$
The last equation defines a conic $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{C} \cap \mathcal{O} = \mathcal{C} \cap \mathcal{E}$.
By Bézout's theorem again, when the intersection is finite, the number of intersection is at most $4 = 2 \times 2$.

Comment: I don't see any $z$ coordinate appearing here; the Cassini ovals have to be considered as space objects, like 2D ovals centered at the origin rotated around the Y-axis, and the circle floating somewhere in space with its center not at the origin. Is your result equivalent? By looking at the 2D ovals and imagining them in 3D I can count up to 4 possible intersections.

Comment: @Petoetje59 The number of intersection is independent of the choice of coordinate system, we choose a coordinate system where the plane holding the circle is the $z = 0$ plane. Under this coordinate system, the equation for intersection of the 3D Oval with the plane doesn't have $z$ coordinate (more precisely, have a constant $z = 0$).  The results when Oval is centered at origin or the circle is centered at origin are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The section of the hyperboloid by the plane of support of the circle is a conic. Two conics can intersect in four points.

Answer (score 0):

Deriving the implicit equation for the 3D Cassinian is easy, $2a$ is the distance between the fixed points, $b$ is the constant.
When the foci lie symmetric to the $XYZ$ origin on the $Y$ axis, the surface can be neatly visualised in *Wolfram Mathematica*, using :

```
ContourPlot3D[(x^2+(y+a)^2+z^2)*(x^2+(y-a)^2+z^2)==b^2,{x,-2*a,2*a},{y,-2*a,2*a},{z,-2*a,2*a},WorkingPrecision->16,PlotRange->Automatic,BoxRatios->Automatic,PlotPoints->50,ContourStyle->Directive[Cyan,Opacity[0.5]],Mesh->None,AxesLabel->{"X","Y","Z"},Ticks->None]
```

The $a$ is the known euclidean distance between transmitter - receiver, the constant $b$ can be calculated as well, so I'll be able to see what shape the particular Cassinian takes and how the circle (aircraft's track) intersects it.